# font-family suggestion in Chrome devtools is commercial-free or not?

Tags: css, fonts

[image]

When I direct edit in Element-tab in dev tools,

there is a recommendation for font-family

so I find `fantasy` font and want to use it for my project,

then now I want to know this font-family is commercially free or not.

—-edit——
I know I got many dislike for this post,
but I will leave this post for who curious this feature. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are all open source and free to use on your commerical or non-commerical web pages.